# Getting a theme related crash only in release mode from Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

I'm getting the error on one of my activities

```
you need to use a theme.appcompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

The activity was using AppCompatActivity but changed to FragmentActivity as I didn't need the action bar, the theme it's using in the manifest inherits from an app compat theme but I changed it to use `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` directly. Not sure what else to try or what's going wrong.

I only get the error with a release apk generated by Jenkins, app works fine in debug mode straight from Android Studio.

Comment: Are you doing a clean build? Does this happen with a release build from your machine?

Comment: It's a clean build but trying to run a release build locally I get an error of unable to compute hash of app/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/release/classes.jar

Comment: I fixed it so I could build a release apk locally and that also works fine but still crashes when using the apk from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem exactly was but I cleared out the repos on the build machine and updated the build tools and support libraries and it's working now.